# SQLIte query returns empty cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-cursor

I am trying to get data from my SQLite database in Android using this query.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Task where taskId = 1 ", null);
```

However the cursor is returned empty, a taskId with value 1 exists.

If I do this

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Task", null);
```

my cursor contains all of the values - including a taskId with value 1.

I have tried all of the following commands as well, neither of them worked:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Task where taskId = " + 1, null);
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Task where taskId = " + "'1'", null);
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Task where taskId = ?", new String[]{"1"});
```

taskId is of type Integer, tried it with Text, too, also didn't work.

Is there something I didn't consider? Help would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT:
Code for creating the database:**

```
CREATE TABLE Task + " (" +
        _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        "taskDescription TEXT, +                
        "taskId INTEGER," +
        "taskName TEXT" + 
        "PreviousTaskID " + "REFERENCES " + "PreviousTasks " + 
        "(" + PreviousTasks._ID + "))"
```

Comment: How about showing some code?

Comment: Can you show the definition of your table?

Comment: Pff, still nothing wrong... are you sure you're not mixing the _id field with taskId??

Comment: I tried it with both _id and taskId - same result :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Cursor cursor = null;
String Query ="SELECT * FROM Task where taskId = 1 ";
cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    // ...
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());

  cursor.close();
}
```

i hope its useful to you..

Answer (score 1):

If you created database for example with 4 fields and used this db then if you add new field you need to recreate database on phone, delete and create it.

Your database must be at /data/data/com.yourapp.package/databases/, use [this](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) or [this](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-sqlite) open it and check if anything wrong.

Remove all spaces :

```
Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM  Task WHERE taskId=1", null);
```

Step the cursor to the first result :

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Use [getInt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractWindowedCursor.html#getInt%28int%29):

```
int taskid = c.getnt(c.getColumnIndex("taskId"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found out what the problem was: When accessing the cursor, I used following code:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
  //stuff
};
```

Instead what I had to do was this:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
do{
  //stuff
} while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

I didn't notice the error when I queried

```
Cursor.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TASK");
```

since my cursor had more than one entry and. But when I queried

```
Cursor.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TASK WHERE taskID=1");
```

the cursor only has one entry which was skipped because of the while-loop.

Comment: FYI, this will fail in case there is no data. You should check the return value of `moveToFirst()`, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean -1 count of elements of cusor by telling "empty", so you just have to use moveToFirst() before.

```java
Cusror c = rawQuery(...); 
// this line is required 
c.moveToFirst();
```

then if you'd try to invoke

```java
c.getCount()
```

it returns != 0 (if the query returns more than 0).